# How do I branch a wire of a flex cable?

Tags: wiring, crimp

I've got a 10" (25 cm) 40-wire flex cable (similar to an IDE cable) with the well-known 2×20-pin plug on one end and a handful of Dupont connectors I will attach to the other end of the wires. See this drawing:

[image: Wiring overview]

My problem is the following: Some wires correspond to more than one output connector! Wire #1 (orange), for instance, corresponds to four output pins, each on a different connector. These plugs will be placed on quite different places, so that crimping a second wire to, say, connector #1 and making it run to connector #2 is not really a viable option to me. Nor does a Wago 222 block work for me, as it's designed for thick power wires.

I would remove the isolation from the corresponding wire and solder the end of the branch wire, but I'm afraid that such a connection will not last very long.

Any suggestions?

Comment: A custom  printed circuit interface board would be a good solution

Comment: Why should it not last? Is it moving all the time? You could also re-isolate the joint with heat-shrink tube...

Comment: @RussellH it sounds like the connectors are not on the same plane... they go to "different places"?!

Comment: @datenheim: The 20 pin connector inputs to a PCB. The PCB wiring cross connects to 5 output connectors. Then run separate cables from each of the 5 to their respective endpoints.

Comment: @RussellH I have already implemented the PCB solution in a different part of my project. Here it won't work because the connectors are attached to subsystems located in very different corners of the enclosure I'm using, and I have no more space left for another board. Sorry!

Comment: @datenheim: It's maybe not moving around all time long, but exposed to vibration! It's gonna be part of an automotive embedded system.

Comment: Wago says the 222 series blocks are good for #28 - 12 AWG or 0.08 - 2.5 sq mm, so do work with small wires.

Comment: Is it relevant to safety, braking, steering?

Comment: @datenheim No. I'd never employ a homebrewn solution for a critical subsystem.

Comment: @Neppomuk Ok, good :) I did only ask because the suggestions given here should be "up to the task". Better think twice and reassure is my thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hot-melt glue, and heatshrink tubing.

After making a soldered splice put some hot melt glue on it and cover it with heat-shrink tubing.

The hot glue will bond the insulation of the wires together, providing strain releif, the heatshring when heated ans shrunk will re-melt and bond to the hot glue prividing more  strain releif and also insulate the splice, and make it look somewhat "professional". you can also purchase heatshrink tubin that had the inside coated with hot-melt glue, which mean you glue and sleeve your splice in a single operation.

[image]
Image credit: "Brand dielectrics"

Comment: Doesn't the heatshrink already provide strain relief if the correct size is chosen? (small enough to bind tightly on the insulation as it shrinks)

Comment: it doesn't shrink with enough force to bind tightly

Comment: jasen: Yep, you are absolutely right. Even the perfect heatshrink tube will never fit snugly enough to provide strain relief.